# Using hashes to round-robin objects between buckets?

Tags: algorithm, hash, round-robin

We have an incoming queue of support cases from customers.

Each support case has at least the following fields:

- Case Number (Unique numeric ID)
- Creation Time (Timestamp)
- Title (Text String)
- Description (Text String)
- Other fields...

We'd like to split these into three distinct buckets, in a repeatable way.

For example, the first case that comes in goes to queue A, the second to queue B, the third to queue C etc.

It doesn't necessarily need to be in that order, but the distribution needs to be equal (or close to equal).

The case number is monotonically increasing but they are *not* sequential (that is, there will be gaps - e.g. case 10005, then case 10400, then case 10405 etc.). The reason is that the case numbers are shared among several categories, but we are only looking at a single specific category of cases.

We don't want to have to maintain a lookup table - but rather I was thinking of generating some kind of hash based on case number + creation time, for example, and then doing a modulus 3 on it?

Question

1. Does the above approach look sane? Any comments?
2. What sort of hashing algorithm, and on what fields should I do it across, in order to get a good distribution for the modulus?

Comment: Sounds fine, but what is your question?

Comment: What sort of hash could I use to do this and get a good distribution?